# Where does a model's drawing information (coordinates, images etc.) belong in an MVP pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvp

I'm writing a small demo application (for proof of concept for a much larger project) that will utilize a passive view MVP architecture in C# (.NET 4.5).

Without going into too much detail, it's an application that allows you to draw out a particular process (similar to Visio) on a large canvas using drag and drop tools and then we run simulations based on what's been drawn and configured.

Now, what people do in our legacy application is set custom images to the process nodes, so it's nice and easy to differentiate between nodes or make it look more like a real world situation.

Where would things like a node's bitmap reside in an MVP pattern?  It's obviously tempting to just stick in the model but this would break the MVP pattern (what if we simply had a command line interface for example?).  Having it as part of the view seems almost too disjointed from the underlying objects themselves.

Also, as a small second question, with a drawing-style application like the one I've described, would these objects views likely be derived from `UserControl` or `CustomControl`?  This seems like a quite a lot of overhead for basically just some bitmaps.

Below is an example of a this very simple node which is acting as a very simple Model.  What would typically happen is as it's state changes, it would look different, i.e. applies a different bitmap.

```
public enum NodeStates{ Idle, Working, Broken, ResourceStarved, Blocked };

public class Node: ModelBase
{
    private string _username;
    private NodeStates _currentState;

    public Node(string username)
    {
        _username = username;
        _currentState = NodeStates.Idle;
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            return _username;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_username != value)
            {
                _username = value;
                NotifyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public NodeStates CurrentState
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentState;
        }

        private set
        {
            if (_currentState != value)
            {
                _currentState = value;
                NotifyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        CurrentState = NodeStates.Working;
        //Todo, schedule work complete time
    }

    public void WorkComplete()
    {
        CurrentState = NodeStates.Idle;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your point about the use of bitmaps and a console-type application is valid. However, I would argue that the Node's bitmap is an attribute of the Node and should remain there.

The form/console output is typically handled by the concrete view. With a passive view flavour of MVP this doesn't fit so well as you would probably be assigning the bitmap via a specific method or property on the view interface. This would mean that a console-based implementation of the view would effectively ignore this and do nothing with it, which I think is where your unease arises.

Looking at the supervising controller flavour, the problem isn't so marked as you would hand a Node to the view and then the view would decide what to render, with the console-based view doing nothing with the bitmap. This, effectively, equates to the same functionality but in a more graceful manner.

Therefore, my answer is: keep the bitmap as an attribute of the Node. If you use passive view, a concrete console-based view does nothing with the bitmap.